# Lame DNS server

Tags: bind

I'm trying to setup my BIND with a domain I own and I'm using dnssy.com and intodns.com to check if everything is ok, but I'm getting errors in both.
The error says that my DNS server is "lame" (which I don't understand what does it mean).

My named.conf

```
options {
    directory "/var/dns";
    pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";
    auth-nxdomain yes;
    datasize default;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    listen-on { 127.0.0.1; 188.165.234.51; };
    listen-on-v6 { ::1; };
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-update { none; };
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-query-cache { any; };
    version none;
    hostname none;
    server-id none;
};
include "/var/dns/autogen-zones";
```

autogen-zones is an autogenerated file which contains the following:

```
zone "localhost" IN {
     type master;
     file "localhost.zone";
     allow-transfer { any; };
};
zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
     type master;
     file "127.0.0.zone";
     allow-transfer { any; };
};
zone "." IN {
     type hint;
     file "root.hint";
};
zone "destinosxures.com" IN {
     type master;
     file "destinosxures.com.zone";
     allow-query { any; };
     allow-transfer { any; };
};
```

Last, my destinosxures zone:

```
$TTL 604800
@ IN SOA ns367310.ovh.net. hostmaster.destinoxures.com. (
  2012030503   ; Serial yyyy/mm/dd/id
       10800   ; Refresh
        3600   ; Retry
     604800   ; Expire
      10800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL

@ IN NS    ns367310.ovh.net.
@ IN NS    sdns2.ovh.net.

ns1     IN A 188.165.234.51
ns2     IN A 188.165.234.51
@       IN A 188.165.234.51
www     IN A 188.165.234.51

http.tcp SRV 0 3 80 destinoxures.com.
https.tcp SRV 1 0 443 destinoxures.com.
```

Oh, by the way, my resolv.conf has:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.251.188.141
```

What is wrong with my config?

Comment: It may be cut-and-paste error, but your `named.conf` lists the zone as `destinosxures.com` while the zonefile itself refers only to `destinoxures.com` (note missing central "s").  If that reflects what's really on your server, then it's definitely a problem.

Comment: @MadHatter Oh my god... That is probably the sillies typo I have ever made. Please copy/paste your comment as an answer so I can accept it and choose it as an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your named.conf lists the zone as `destinosxures.com` while the zonefile itself refers only to `destinoxures.com` (note missing central "s"). If that reflects what's really on your server, then it's definitely a problem.

And may I in passing **thank you for not obscuring the domain name** in the question; if you had, we'd likely never have found the answer.  Others who are posting questions, particularly DNS questions, please take note.

Comment: I agree, not obscuring the domain name was vital for my question :)

Comment: one more question (exactly same config). I'm getting this error: "Glue is not provided by your nameservers. You should add A records for your nameservers into your domain zone to fix this.". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I see some missing. The name "ns367310" is not pointing to an IP address. This is the name written as "hostname". So, you have to add the following line there in the zone file:
ns367310 IN A 188.165.234.51
the following 4 lines stay unchanged:
ns1     IN A 188.165.234.51
ns2     IN A 188.165.234.51
@       IN A 188.165.234.51
www     IN A 188.165.234.51
But the followings 2 lines needs a "s" in that position:
http.tcp SRV 0 3 80 destino"s"xures.com.
https.tcp SRV 1 0 443 destino"s"xures.com.
This "s" have to be added because the zone is called : zone "destinosxures.com", and related file also: "destinosxures.com.zone"
I hope it's not a wrong answer. If yes , please reply me !!!

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault. I am not sure if you noticed, but the question was 7 years old and had an accepted answer already. Your efforts might be best served helping with any number of [new and unanswered questions](https://serverfault.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest).

Comment: Do not worry , I was noticed regarding the age of article.