# Is my DNS setup correctly?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have some doubts about the DNS setup for mydomain
I have a domain, which I'm not using yet, but is active
I have a subdomain off this which i am using, the website 'seems' to be working ok
Google picks it up, Bing does now, but took a while, 3 weeks approx

Reasons for doubts:-
I've tried checking the subdomain at various sites, most of them say that there is a problem.
@ http://www.dnssy.com i get the following:-

NS records at parent nameserver:    Your NS records at your parent nameserver are:
Provided by a.gtld-servers.net -> nameserver1   ..............        Info

Nameservers listed at parent:   No nameservers found at parent nameserver.  ..........Fail

I've tried mail.google.com and get the same results, So my 1st thoughts were this must be ok. But now i have my doubts.
Also email client only works when set to IMAP, does not work with POP3, tried various clients. also is very slow, with both domain & subdomain

My DNS from WHM is as follows

```
mydomain.com    86400   in  SOA nameserver1.

mydomain.com    86400   in  NS  nameserver1.
mydomain.com    86400   in  NS  nameserver2.
mydomain.com    14400   in  A   1.1.1.1
localhost               in  A   2.2.2.2
mydomain.com            in  MX  0   mail.mydomain.com.
mail                    in  A   1.1.1.1
www                     in  CNAME   mydomain.com.
ftp                     in  A   1.1.1.1
mydomain.com            in  TXT "v=s******************"
default_domainkey       in  TXT "v=D**********verylongcode"
server                  in  CNAME   mydomain.com.
webmail                 in  A   1.1.1.1
mysubdomain             in  A   1.1.1.1
www.mysubdomain         in  A   1.1.1.1
default_domainkey.mysubdomain   TXT "v=D**********anotherverylongcode"
mysubdomain             in  TXT "v=s******************"
Long hex number         in  CNAME   verify.bing.com
```

Email Routing is set to Auto detect config: Local

i'm scared of changing anything in the DNS due to lack of knowledge and importance of DNS and cannot see any solutions for this on stack overflow or any other site

My questions are:-
a) Do i need to add an entry to point the subdomain directly at the nameservers? ie

```
mysubdomain in  NS nameserver1 (& 2)
```

b)Is there a problem or something missing from the DNS that will cause the email problems.
c) Can someone give my DNS a 'health check' please.

Very grateful for any help with the above.

Comment: Are `nameserver1` and `nameserver2` yours? If so, do they have IP addresses?

Comment: If you have a DNS issue, please add the real domain if at all possible. It's so much easier to diagnose a problem if you can look into the actual responses of `dig` & co.

Comment: I completely endorse what SvW has said about giving the real data.  If you're dubious, take a look at the original poster's comments on http://serverfault.com/questions/485137/lame-dns-server/485148#485148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) yes and nameserver1 and 2 (and 3 and...) MUST be accessible machines with official names,
e.g.

```
utich.edu.              1800    IN      NS      dns.cs.wiuc.edu.
utich.edu.              1800    IN      NS      dns.itd.utich.edu.
utich.edu.              1800    IN      NS      dns2.itd.utich.edu.
```

what you have now appear to be unpublished local machine names. This is what the warning:

```
NS records at parent nameserver: Your NS records at your parent nameserver are: 
Provided by a.gtld-servers.net -> nameserver1 .............. Info
```

is about.

b) Hard to tell - you do have an MX so IF mail.mydomain.com. is correctly configured you shoudl be covered (a pretty big if)

c) http://www.robtex.com/ is your friend

I'll also add:

d) the localhost entry is really funky, serves no discernible purpose and may cause harm; the subdomain stuff is also rather unusual.

Comment: d)Should I have a localhost entry? or is it the IP address? (127.0.0.1) Do I delete it? The DNS for the subdomain was setup auto when I created the subdomain c)going to http://www.robtex.com/ now to find out more

Comment: Look, from what I see, everything and your uncle in your zone (cafullerweb.com) is pointing to the same IP - 209.239.112.213. While formally (perhaps - but then having 2 NSs is pretty useless) correct this is 99.9% not what one expects, 90% not what you want unless you have a pretty unusual machine sitting at 209.239.112.213.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i apologize for the delay, as have been researching your answer.