# DNS Records not found for a website

Tags: domain-name-system

I am running a dedicated server.

The server is running two sites. This morning one website is not working and I found that there is a problem with the dns settings. I don't know how it happened very suddenly.

The other website is working properly.

```
nslookup @domainname.com

Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find @domainname.com: NXDOMAIN
```

I checked online dns tools and they are reporting errors.

nslookup for another site is also not working

But dig for another site is working properly.

```
dig @domainname.com

dig: couldn't get address for 'domainname.com': not found
```

and ping is reporting

```
ping: unknown host domainname.com


dig SOA sitename.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> SOA sitename.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 25377
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sitename.com.              IN      SOA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
co.in.                  879     IN      SOA     a0.cctld.afilias-nst.info. noc.afilias-nst.info. 2008728028 600 900 2592000 86400

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 30 17:36:06 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 99

cat /etc/resolv.conf 

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I tried one online website for nslookup.

```
DNS server handling your query: localhost
 DNS server's address:  127.0.0.1#53

 ** server can't find domain.co.in: NXDOMAIN
```

domain name : justforfun.co.in

Comment: Check in your DNS management if that service is up and running.

Comment: So check your DNS settings using the control panel through your host.

Comment: I don't have any control panel

Comment: If you have registered a domain name, you have a control panel.

Comment: I checked that it has the correct name servers

Comment: What does `dig SOA domainname.com` say?

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @user192058 - the details of your question are pretty vague and you don't give much to work with here.  Before the question gets closed as "unclear" it would behoove you to include additional details like the actual domain name in question, any changes made recently to its dns zone, etc.

Comment: Adding your actual domain name here is fine by us.  Doing this helps greatly with DNS questions.  If you don't want to do that, you might want to check the status page or the Twitter feed of your DNS provider.  If that's fine, also check if the domain has expired in the last few days.

Comment: Domain is not expired. I am not using any DNS Provider. Is it really important to share the domain name?

Comment: @user192058 It's really hard to diagnose DNS problems without knowing the domain name. So yes, if you want help, it is kind of important.

Comment: It definitely can be: see http://serverfault.com/questions/485137/lame-dns-server/485148#485148 for an example of where it was absolutely vital.

Comment: I just added my domain name! Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: I tried to add a new domain to the server which is successfully added and working. But this one, which was working properly, is not working.

Comment: What did you change on September 29th (yesterday) in regards to this domain? It seems what ever that change was, caused your name servers to disappear...

Comment: It is not working today. I tried many things still I cant find the problem. But other sites are working. So I recreated the DNS settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://info.info/index.php?q=faq/7 The whois on your domain returns `Status: Hold` which likely means that your nameservers are not configured [properly] at the registrar.

Further Investigation reveals the following:

```
DNS server handling your query: NS2.FUNNY.ORG.IN
 DNS server's address:  173.249.151.139#53

 Name:  JUSTFORFUN.CO.IN
 Address: 173.249.151.139
```

NS1.FUNNY.ORG.IN does not resolve to an IP address. This is likely why the registrar placed the domain in hold status and refuses to publish it to the zone. Contact the admin responsible for ns1.funny.org.in or switch to a different DNS provider.

---

Or at least it didn't appear to be resolving ns1.funny.org.in a minute ago..

Comment: How did you get those details? Where can I check them?

Comment: Whois: `http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/results.jsp?domain=justforfun.co.in` && `dig @ns1.funny.org.in justforfun.co.in`

Comment: I would contact the registrar and ask for assistance. It appears that they have put your domain on hold status for one reason or another.

Comment: which registrar? justforfun.co.in?

Comment: how do I prove them it is in the hold status? I already contacted and explained but they didn't accept it.

Comment: http://who.is/whois/justforfun.co.in - The various online whois lookupp providers respond back with the `Status: Hold` line present. If they don't accept that as evidence of an issue and help (or at least explain why it is not an issue), Have them open up the transfer hold on the domain and threaten to move your registration to a new provider.