# DNS: Wildcard Subdomain with exempt subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system

I have domain `example.com`. I have a static cdn subdomain where I want to serve all my static files from called `scdn.example.com`. I want all wildcard subdomains to be redirected to `example.com`. Is this redirection done through DNS or my webserver? In the DNS I added a CNAME `*.example.com` record and pointed it to `example.com`. However, this wildcard CNAME record is blocking the `scdn.example.com` one. How do I make it so `scdn.example.com` can point to some IPv4 address and not being included into the wildcard subdomain? I even pointed `scdn.example.com` to an IPv4 with an "A" Record but the wildcard is taking priority.

I hope that makes sense, if not, please let me know.

Comment: That makes sense, but what you want is also normal behaviour for a well-behaved DNS server.  What DNS server are you using?  Or is this some outsourced web-based horror?  Any chance you could un-redact the domain?  It's really helpful to be able to see what's going on with DNS questions.

Comment: @MadHatter I am using AWS Route 53. I don't think I am allowed to un-redact the domain. I will consult the technical contact and see  if I can un-redact.

Comment: I've just checked it with some of the domains I manage on Route 53, and it's as I'd expect: the specific records override the wildcard, which I think is what you want.  Unless you're willing to un-redact your domain, I don't think we can help much.

Comment: In case it helps, see http://serverfault.com/questions/485137/lame-dns-server for an earlier example of a DNS question where having the domain name was completely vital to solving the problem.  If that had been redacted, we'd never have been able to help.